# Where does Inversion of Control arise during this example of Dependency Injection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I am totally confused. There are many sources out there contradicting each other about the definitions of Dependency Injection and Inversion of Control. Here is the gist of my understanding without many additional detail, that in most cases made things more convoluted for me: Dependency Injection means that instead of my function conjuring the required dependencies, it is given the dependency as a parameter. Inversion of Control means that, for instance when you use a framework it is the framework that calls your userland code, and the control is inversed because in the 'default' case your code would be calling specific implementations in a library.

Now as I understand, somehow along the way, because my function that doesn't conjure up the dependencies anymore but gets it as an argument Inversion of Control magically happens when I use dependency injection like below.

So here is a silly example I wrote for myself to wrap my head around the idea:

getTime.js

```
function getTime(hour) {
  return `${hour} UTC`
}

module.exports.getTime = getTime
```

welcome.js

```
function welcomeUser(name, hour) {
  const getTime = require('./time').getTime
  const time = getTime(`${hour} pm`)

  return(`Hello ${name}, the time is ${time}!`)
}

const result = welcomeUser('Joe', '11:00')
console.log(result)

module.exports.welcomeUser = welcomeUser
```

welcome.test.js

```
const expect = require('chai').expect
const welcomeUser = require('./welcome').welcomeUser

describe('Welcome', () => {
  it('Should welcome user', () => {
    
    // But we would want to test how the welcomeUser calls the getTime function
    expect(welcomeUser('Joe', '10:00')).to.equal('Hello Joe, the time is 10:00 pm UTC!')

  })
})
```

The problem now is that the call of the getTime function is implemented in the welcome.js function, and it can not be intercepted by a test. What we would like to do is to test how the getTime function is called, and we can't to that this way.
The other problem is that the getTime function is pretty much harcoded, so we can't mock it, and that could be useful because we only want to test the welcomUser function separately, as that is the use of a unit test (the getTime function could be simultaneously implemented, for instance).

So the main problem is that the code is tightly coupled, it's harder to test and it is just wreaking havoc all around the place. Now let's use dependency injection:

getTime.js

```
function getTime(hour) {
  return `${hour} UTC`
}

module.exports.getTime = getTime
```

welcome.js

```
const getTime = require('./time').getTime

function welcomeUser(name, hour, dependency) {
  const time = dependency(hour)

  return(`Hello ${name}, the time is ${time}!`)
}

const result = welcomeUser('Joe', '10:00', getTime)
console.log(result)

module.exports.welcomeUser = welcomeUser
```

welcome.test.js

```
const expect = require('chai').expect
const welcomeUser = require('./welcome').welcomeUser

describe('welcomeUser', () => {
  it('should call getTime with the right hour value', () => {
    
    const fakeGetTime = function(hour) {
      expect(hour).to.equal('10:00')
    }

    // 'Joe' as an argument isn't even neccessary, but it's nice to leave it there
    welcomeUser('Joe', '10:00', fakeGetTime)
  })

  it('should log the current message to the user', () => {
    
    // Let's stub the getTime function
    const fakeGetTime = function(hour) {
      return `${hour} pm UTC`
    }

    expect(welcomeUser('Joe', '10:00', fakeGetTime)).to.equal('Hello Joe, the time is 10:00 pm UTC!')
  })
})
```

As I understood, what I did above was Dependency Injection. Multiple sources claim that Dependency Injection is not possible without Inversion of Control. But where does Inversion of Control come into the picture?

Also what about the regular JavaScript workflow, where you just import the dependencies globally and use them later in your functions, instead of require-ing them inside of the functions or giving it to them as parameters?

Comment: Dependency injection is when an outside *thing* gives you the dependencies. Likely some framework. At any rate, if you require, say a DB connection to operate, you get some kind of DB connection. Since DI is also IoC, you don't actually control what DB connection that is. You likely have a bit of config describing it but your code does not care - all it knows is there is some database there and it can interact with it via this object. You might connect to MySQL, or Oracle, or SQLite or even a fake database. That's not for your code to decide, it's the IoC/DI mechanism that supplies it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check Martin Fowler's article on IoC and DI. https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html

IoC: Very generic word. This inversion can happen in many ways.

DI: Can be viewed as one branch of this generic word IoC.

So in your code when you specifically implements DI, one would say your code has this general idea of IoC in the flavor of DI. What really inversed is, the default way of looking for behavior (default way is writing it within the method, inversed way would be getting behavior injected from outside).